# Trying to create a function that computes the sum and averages of numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, tuples

Im extremely new to programming, and there's a progamming class in python that I need to take. Unfortunately, functions are such a weak point for me. 
Can someone help me solve this problem:

```
test_data = [10, 23.4, 45.6, 98.7, 34.3]
(data_sum, data_average) = sum_and_average(test_data)
print("The sum of the data is {:.3f} and the average is {:.3f}".format( data_sum, data_average ))
```

"write a function that takes in a list of floats, computes both the sum and the average of those numbers. 
The function should be named sum_and_average
The function should return both the sum and the average using a tuple, 
with the sum being first element in the tuple and the average being the second in the tuple."

this is what i have so far:

```
def sum_and_average(data_sum,data_average):

    data_average = sum(test_data) / len(test_data)

    data_sum = (sum(test_data)

    return data_sum and data_average
```

I don't think this is correct. I'm not too sure what to put in the parenthesis for def sum_and average. If someone can just guide me in the right direction it would mean a ton!!
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to pass one argument `test_data` into your function, then your `return` should be formatted `(total, average)` to create a `tuple`, try not to use same naming system in your function as the variables you are passing

```
def sum_and_average(data):
    average = sum(data) / len(data)
    total = sum(data)
    return (total, average)

test_data = [10, 23.4, 45.6, 98.7, 34.3]

data_sum, data_average  = sum_and_average(test_data)
print('The sum of the data is {:.3f} and the average is {:.3f}'.format(data_sum, data_average))
```

> ```
> The sum of the data is 212.000 and the average is 42.400
> ```

Comment: thank you so much!! It seems I wasn't as wrong as I thought i could have been. I really appreciate the help!!! thank you again

Comment: @Sra18 No problem ! Would appreciate if you accepted solution :)

Comment: i will gladly do that! How do i accept the solution? I upvoted your answer, but is that the same thing?

Comment: @sra18 Haha no worries , Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. A few things, you don't want `sum_data` and `data_average` as inputs as those are actually your outputs. Put data as your input. I took out a parenthesis to make the code run. Also, you want to return a tuple, so you want to return `(data_sum, data_average)`:

```
test_data = [10, 23.4, 45.6, 98.7, 34.3] 

def sum_and_average(data):
    data_average = sum(test_data) / len(test_data)
    data_sum = sum(test_data)
    return (data_sum, data_average)

data_sum, data_average  = sum_and_average(test_data)
```

Output:

```
(212.0, 42.4)
```

Thus when you call `print('The sum of the data is {:.3f} and the average is {:.3f}'.format(data_sum, data_average))`, you will print the following string: `The sum of the data is 212.000 and the average is 42.400`

Comment: Go for the whole shabang print the expected output statement as well xD, you have evertyhing you need

Answer (score 0):

In addition to already good answers, this is what I would use:

```
def sum_and_average(test_data):
     data_average = sum(test_data) / len(test_data)
     data_sum = (sum(test_data))
```

Missing Parenthesis in your code.

```
     return(data_sum, data_average)
```

This returns two values - sum and average. If you use "and" it would return the sum and not the average.

```
test_data = [10, 23.4, 45.6, 98.7, 34.3]
(data_sum, data_average) = sum_and_average(test_data)
print("The sum of the data is {:.3f} and the average is {:.3f}".format( data_sum, data_average ))
```

You have to note that the order of def and main does not matter in this particular case.